# Cifs mount a windows share that goes offline

Tags: centos, mount, cifs

I have a windows share on my workstation that I need on my CentOS 7 server.
I have this set up in my fstab as the following:

`//XXX.XXX.X.XX/Share   /mnt/workstation        cifs    username=X,password=X 0 0`

This is working as long as my workstation is online.
Once my workstation is offline it'll give errors on the /mnt/ directory and WinSCP will not connect.
I have to umount the share and remount it for it to work again.

Is there a better way to do this instead of remounting the drive every time?

Comment: Have you looked at `autofs`?  It mounts on demand.

Comment: Wouldn't this still cause issues if it's being accessed while it's offline?

Comment: To a certain extent.  If it went offline while in use then you would suffer issues.  However, `autofs` automatically unmounts too after a period, so if the share went offline when nobody was accessing it then it wouldn't cause any issues.  It should do the unmount/remount for you.

Comment: Of course, I don't know your situation, but would it not be better to have the share on the server and have the workstation use that instead? Or, if that's not possible, a scheduled `rsync` setup that copies from one to the other?

Comment: Well it's a drive in my workstation that my Plex media server uses for its library. I'm not sure how plex handles autofs but it's sure worth a try